# bindParam is not completing the sql query

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm new to PDO statements and so far I've managed to work with it, use prepared statements and many things, until today.

I have two querys, the first retrieve some data, store the results and then the second query uses that data to retrieve the final data. I'm working on a bad designed DB, that's why I have to do weird things.

The first query gets the year of start and the year of end of a sport league. Then, the year is passed to the second query to get data between those years (WHERE).

The problem is that bindParam seems to not work, it doesn't bind the parameter, shows a ?, and then the SQL throws the following exception:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near ''0701' AND ?'0630' ORDER BY e.FECHA DESC' at line 5
```

The SQL:

```
$sqlQueryAuxiliar = "SELECT ano_inicio, ano_fin
                     FROM TEMPORADAS
                     ORDER BY ano_inicio DESC
                     LIMIT 1;";

$sqlQuery = "SELECT  e.id, e.JORNADA, DATE_FORMAT(e.FECHA, '%Y-%m-%d'),
             e.HORA, c1.nombre_temporada, c2.nombre_temporada
             FROM    ENCUENTROS AS e
             JOIN    CLUBS AS c1 ON (e.COD_EQUIL = c1.siglas)
             JOIN    CLUBS AS c2 ON (e.COD_EQUIV = c2.siglas)
             WHERE   e.FECHA BETWEEN :anoInicio'0701' AND :anoFinal'0630'
             ORDER BY e.FECHA DESC;";
```

And this is the PHP code:

```
$this->_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmtAux = $this->_db->prepare($sqlQueryAuxiliar);
$stmtAux->execute();
$fetched = $stmtAux->fetchAll();
$stmtAux = null;
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sqlQuery);
$stmt->bindParam(':anoInicio', $fetched[0][0], PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$stmt->bindParam(':anoFinal', $fetched[0][1], PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $partidos[] = $row;
}
$stmt = null;
```

Comment: I think the error related to single quotas `'0701'` and `'0630'`, escape them and try again

Comment: What's the `'0701'` after `:anoInicio`, or the `'0630'` after `:anoFinal` supposed to be? IS this an attempt at concatenating numbers with bind variables?

Comment: @MarkBaker Month and day. The result should be: 'YearMonthDay', like '20130701'. This database does not use standard timestamps and it's a pain in the neck to work.

Comment: Then you'll need to concatenate those texts to your $fetched values __before__ binding, rather than try and embed them in your statement, as Olaf has shown in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stands to reason, you're building invalid sql:

```
 WHERE   e.FECHA BETWEEN :anoInicio'0701' AND :anoFinal'0630'
```

would be built as basically

```
 WHERE e.FETCHA BETWEEN foobar'0701' AND barbaz'0630'
```

which is a syntax error.

You probably want

```
WHERE e.FETCH BETWEEN concat(:anoInicio, '0701') AND concat(:anoFinal, '0630')
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, that was finally worked. Olaf method still caused errors.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot concatenate strings in your query this way. Change your query to

```
SELECT  e.id, e.JORNADA, DATE_FORMAT(e.FECHA, '%Y-%m-%d'), e.HORA, c1.nombre_temporada, c2.nombre_temporada
              FROM    ENCUENTROS AS e
              JOIN    CLUBS AS c1 ON (e.COD_EQUIL = c1.siglas)
              JOIN    CLUBS AS c2 ON (e.COD_EQUIV = c2.siglas)
              WHERE   e.FECHA BETWEEN :anoInicio AND :anoFinal
              ORDER BY e.FECHA DESC
```

and the `bindParam`s to

```
$stmt->bindValue(':anoInicio', $fetched[0][0] . '0701', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':anoFinal', $fetched[0][1] . '0630', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: If I do that, this exception is raised:
`Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference` at
`$stmt->bindParam(':anoInicio', $fetched[0][0] . '0701', PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);`

Comment: Ok, I had to define the variables instead of passing an array.

`$foo = $fetched[0][0];
$stmt->bindParam(':anoInicio', $foo . '0701', PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bound parameters you should not also be passing in a hard-coded value in your query..

```
"SELECT  e.id, e.JORNADA, DATE_FORMAT(e.FECHA, '%Y-%m-%d'), e.HORA, c1.nombre_temporada, c2.nombre_temporada
          FROM    ENCUENTROS AS e
          JOIN    CLUBS AS c1 ON (e.COD_EQUIL = c1.siglas)
          JOIN    CLUBS AS c2 ON (e.COD_EQUIV = c2.siglas)
          WHERE   e.FECHA BETWEEN :anoInicio AND :anoFinal
          ORDER BY e.FECHA DESC;";
```